# Passing a returned string into a function as reference without assigning it to a string variable

Tags: c++, string

I have a function defined as:

```
void func(string & str_alias)
{...}
```

And in my main function

```
int main()
{
    string a;
    func((a="Cat said: ")+"Meow");
}
```

The compiler would report that

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}’
```

Though I know if I change the main function into:

```
int main()
{
    string a;
    func(a=((a="Cat said: ")+"Meow"));
}
```

The code would pass with no issues. But I still wonder why the returned string cannot be passed to the function as a reference. Why do I have to assign it to another string variable?

Thanks.

Comment: `std::string::operator=` returns a reference to the stream. `std::string::operator+` returns a copy of the resulting concatenation. This copy is an rvalue and can't be bound to an lvalue-reference.

Comment: When I said "stream" I meant "string". And when I said lvalue-reference I meant *non-const* lvalue-reference because rvalues can in fact bind to const lvalue-references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make it take const reference to std::string, it should compile.

This is because the last thing you do in the first function call is calling `std::string operator+(const std::string&, const char*)`, which as you see returns std::string, not reference, and since it not stored anywhere, it is rvalue, which can't be bound to lvalue-reference.

The second example compiles, because the last thing you do is assign it to the variable `a`, which calls `std::string& operator=(const char*)`, which as you can see returns reference, so it can be used as non-const reference by itself.

Thanks to 0x499602D2 for correction.

Comment: Thanks~ I think I should read up a bit about the rvalue thing. :)

Answer (score 3):

As long you don't need to change the passed reference, you could easily avoid this by changing your function signature to

```
void func(const string & str_alias)
       // ^^^^^
{...}
```

and simply call

```
func(string("Cat said: ") + "Meow");
```

(see [live demo](http://ideone.com/YVNk8P))

If you'll need to change the reference parameter, you must have an lvalue to be modified. Nevertheless writing

```
func(a=string("Cat said: ")+"Meow");
```

is sufficient (see the [**live demo**](http://ideone.com/nwx5z7)).

Comment: "Cat said: " + "Meow" wont compile, because there is no operator for 2 const char*s as far as I know. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the rvalue, lvalue thing.